# Что за элемент отображается в дебагере мозилы? Как его можно убрать?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, есть менюшка, которая выводится циклом с CMS, тоисть все элементы по идее должны быть одинаковы, но в дебагере присутсвуют пробелы (как я понял)
, как их можно убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
{% unless level_limit %}
{% assign level_limit = 2 %}
{% endunless %}

{% unless show_icon %}
  {% assign show_icon = false %}
{% endunless %}

{% if source_type == 'collection' %}

  {% assign prev_link_level = 1 %}
  {% assign root_level = collections[source_handle].level %}

  <ul class="{{ menu_class }} menu level-1">

    {% for link in collections[source_handle].flatten_branch %}

      {% assign node_level = link.level | minus: root_level %}
      {% assign _in_limit = level_limit | minus: node_level %}
      {% assign _next_level_in_limit = _in_limit | minus: 1 %}

      {% assign show_level = false %}
      {% if _in_limit >= 0 %}
        {% assign show_level = true %}
      {% endif %}

      {% assign show_next_level = false %}
      {% if link.subcollections.size > 0 and  _next_level_in_limit >= 0 %}
        {% assign show_next_level = true %}
      {% endif %}

      {% assign current = '' %}

      {% if show_level %}

        {% if link.current? %}
          {% assign current = 'is-current' %}
        {% endif %}

        {% assign level_difference = prev_link_level | minus: link.level | plus: root_level %}

        {% if level_difference > 0 %}
          {% for i in (1..level_difference) %}
            </ul>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        <li class="{{ menu_class }}-item menu-item level-{{ node_level }} {{ current }}">
          {% if show_icon %}
            <span class="{{ menu_class }}-icon menu-icon level-{{ node_level }}"></span>
          {% endif %}

          <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="{{ menu_class }}-link menu-link level-{{ node_level }}">{{ link.title }}</a>

          {% if show_next_level %}

          <div class="{{ menu_class }} menu level-{{ node_level | plus: 1 }}">
          <div class="container level-2-list-wrap">
            {% if menu_type != 'mobile' %}
              {% if block_lists.horizontal-menu-img.blocks.size > 0 %}
                <div class="header-menu-item-img-wrap">
                  {% for block in block_lists.horizontal-menu-img.blocks %}
                    {% assign link_handle = block.handle | split: '__' %} 
                    {% if link.handle == link_handle[0] %}
                      <a href="{{ block.url }}" class="header-menu-item-img">
                        <div style="background-image: url({{ block.image }})" class="header-menu-item-bg">

                        </div>
                        <div class="header-menu-item-title">
                          {{ block.description }}
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
              {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            <ul class="level-2-list {% if link.handle == 'podarki' %}level-2-list-col-1{% endif %} ">

          {% endif %}

        </li>

        {% assign prev_link_level = node_level %}

        {% if forloop.last %}
          {% assign prev_link_level = node_level | minus: 1 %}
          {% for i in (1..prev_link_level) %}

                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

      {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% else %}
  <ul class="{{ menu_class }} menu">

    {% for link in linklists[source_handle].links %}

      {% assign current = '' %}
      {% if link.current? %}
        {% assign current = 'is-current' %}
      {% endif %}

      <li class="{{ menu_class }}-item menu-item level-1 {{ current }}">
        {% if show_icon %}
          <span class="{{ menu_class }}-icon menu-icon level-1"></span>
        {% endif %}
        <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="{{ menu_class }}-link menu-link level-1">
          {{ link.title }}
        </a>
      </li>

    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endif %}

{% assign prev_link_level = null %}
{% assign source_handle = null %}
{% assign menu_class = null %}
{% assign source_type = null %}
{% assign show_icon = null %}
{% assign level_limit = null %}
```

Comment: Разметку в вопрос добавь.

Comment: Я имел в виду html-разметку.

Answer (score 3):

Метод научного тыка подсказывает, что фаерфокс таким образом показывает текстовые узлы, состоящие только из пробельных символов

[image]

Соответственно, чтобы он пропал, нужно в исходном коде убрать между `</li>` и `<li>` все пробельные символы (перенос строки это тоже пробельный символ). Но если от этого не едет вёрстка, то какой в этом смысл? :)

Comment: Мой FF 54.0b11 показывает пробельные символы так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Lbw.png

Comment: @Qwertiy попробую предположить, что зависит от ОС

Comment: Верстка не едет, но добавляет баг JS скрипту (пропадает hover на элементе, когда передвигается курсор с одного элемента на другой) Поудалял все пробелы между началом и концом <li> - не помогает, к сожалению(

Comment: @Виктор в JS есть способы не смешивать текстовые и нетекстовые узлы (`children` вместо `childNodes`, `nextElementSibling` вместо `nextSibling`, `firstElementChild` вместо `firstChild` и т.д.), поэтому предположу, что правильнее будет скрипт поправить

Comment: К тому же я слышал, что некоторые браузеры (касается фокса или нет, не помню) могут добавлять пустые текстовые узлы между элементами, даже если там никакого текста и никаких пробелов нет, так что лучше всё-таки скрипт поправить)

Comment: Возможно, но ведь также присутствует визуальный баг, между теми где есть и где нету пробелов http://prntscr.com/ff3g78 , это очень странно, почему у одних есть, а у других нету, ведь по сути перебирается циклом и по идее сами блоки должны быть одинаковы (кстати и в хроме и в мозиле также)

Comment: @Виктор а это уже на отдельный вопрос тянет, с html-кодом (лучше не шаблоном как тут) и css-стилями

Answer (score 0):

Просто текстовый узел:

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Первый</li>
  ○
  <li>Второй</li>
  ○
  <li>Третий</li>
</ul>
```

И скриншот из devtools FF:

> [image: Скриншот]

Comment: Текстовый узел, но явно не тот, что в примере

Comment: @andreymal, да ну? Добавил скриншот в ответ.

Comment: А теперь немного магии :) https://i.imgur.com/6pD9Sya.png

Comment: @andreymal, запости отдельным ответом. Кстати, для пробелов мой лис показывает другой знак, так что я не знаю, что ты там добавил))

Comment: А как такое чудо убрать?)

Comment: @Виктор, devtools показывают то, что есть на старнице. Убирать ничего не нужно. Ну либо нужно, но со страницы и по другим причинам.