# Консоль браузера, непонятные элементы

Tags: html, браузер

[image: **консоль**]

Простите за нубский вопрос, но откуда появляются прямоугольники с точкой и как от них избавиться? Я перетряхнул весь код и не могу понять, откуда они взялись.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674399/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это текстовые узлы, состоящие только из пробельных символов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я поудалял все пробелы, код теперь в строчку там, где цикл начинается и заканчивается, визуально выглядит не очень, зато все исчезло и 'nth-of-type' теперь работает корректно